# directx mesh from file pixelated

Tags: c++, directx

I have designed a 3ds model in 3d studio max and with pandax exporter i have exported it to a .x file... But when i load it to my c++ program it's all pixelated and distorted. when i load it in directx viewer (microsoft tool) it's all ok... any ideas and help is more than welcomed!!!

Here is the code i use (yes yes is one from microsoft sdk)!!!

```
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// File: Meshes.cpp
//
// Desc: For advanced geometry, most apps will prefer to load pre-authored
//       Meshes from a file. Fortunately, when using Meshes, D3DX does most of
//       the work for this, parsing a geometry file and creating vertx buffers
//       (and index buffers) for us. This tutorial shows how to use a D3DXMESH
//       object, including loading it from a file and rendering it. One thing
//       D3DX does not handle for us is the materials and textures for a mesh,
//       so note that we have to handle those manually.
//
//       Note: one advanced (but nice) feature that we don't show here is that
//       when cloning a mesh we can specify the FVF. So, regardless of how the
//       mesh was authored, we can add/remove normals, add more texture
//       coordinate sets (for multi-texturing), etc.
//
// Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <Windows.h>
#include <mmsystem.h>
#include <d3dx9.h>
#pragma warning( disable : 4996 ) // disable deprecated warning 
#include <strsafe.h>
#include <D3DX9Mesh.h>
#pragma warning( default : 4996 )




//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Global variables
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
LPDIRECT3D9         g_pD3D = NULL; // Used to create the D3DDevice
LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9   g_pd3dDevice = NULL; // Our rendering device

LPD3DXMESH          g_pMesh = NULL; // Our mesh object in sysmem
D3DMATERIAL9*       g_pMeshMaterials = NULL; // Materials for our mesh
LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9* g_pMeshTextures = NULL; // Textures for our mesh
DWORD               g_dwNumMaterials = 0L;   // Number of mesh materials




//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Name: InitD3D()
// Desc: Initializes Direct3D
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
HRESULT InitD3D( HWND hWnd )
{
    // Create the D3D object.
    if( NULL == ( g_pD3D = Direct3DCreate9( D3D_SDK_VERSION ) ) )
        return E_FAIL;

    // Set up the structure used to create the D3DDevice. Since we are now
    // using more complex geometry, we will create a device with a zbuffer.
    D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS d3dpp;
    ZeroMemory( &d3dpp, sizeof( d3dpp ) );
    d3dpp.Windowed = TRUE;
    d3dpp.SwapEffect = D3DSWAPEFFECT_DISCARD;
    d3dpp.BackBufferFormat = D3DFMT_UNKNOWN;
    d3dpp.EnableAutoDepthStencil = TRUE;
    d3dpp.AutoDepthStencilFormat = D3DFMT_D16;

    // Create the D3DDevice
    if( FAILED( g_pD3D->CreateDevice( D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT, D3DDEVTYPE_HAL, hWnd,
                                      D3DCREATE_SOFTWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING,
                                      &d3dpp, &g_pd3dDevice ) ) )
    {
        return E_FAIL;
    }

    // Turn on the zbuffer
    g_pd3dDevice->SetRenderState( D3DRS_ZENABLE, TRUE );

    // Turn on ambient lighting 
    g_pd3dDevice->SetRenderState( D3DRS_AMBIENT, 0xffffffff );

    return S_OK;
}




//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Name: InitGeometry()
// Desc: Load the mesh and build the material and texture arrays
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
HRESULT InitGeometry()
{
    LPD3DXBUFFER pD3DXMtrlBuffer;

    // Load the mesh from the specified file
    if( FAILED( D3DXLoadMeshFromX( L"Tiger.x", D3DXMESH_SYSTEMMEM,
                                   g_pd3dDevice, NULL,
                                   &pD3DXMtrlBuffer, NULL, &g_dwNumMaterials,
                                   &g_pMesh ) ) )
    {
        // If model is not in current folder, try parent folder
        if( FAILED( D3DXLoadMeshFromX( L"..\\Tiger.x", D3DXMESH_SYSTEMMEM,
                                       g_pd3dDevice, NULL,
                                       &pD3DXMtrlBuffer, NULL, &g_dwNumMaterials,
                                       &g_pMesh ) ) )
        {
            MessageBox( NULL, L"Could not find tiger.x", L"Meshes.exe", MB_OK );
            return E_FAIL;
        }
    }

    // We need to extract the material properties and texture names from the 
    // pD3DXMtrlBuffer
    D3DXMATERIAL* d3dxMaterials = ( D3DXMATERIAL* )pD3DXMtrlBuffer->GetBufferPointer();
    g_pMeshMaterials = new D3DMATERIAL9[g_dwNumMaterials];
    if( g_pMeshMaterials == NULL )
        return E_OUTOFMEMORY;
    g_pMeshTextures = new LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9[g_dwNumMaterials];
    if( g_pMeshTextures == NULL )
        return E_OUTOFMEMORY;

    for( DWORD i = 0; i < g_dwNumMaterials; i++ )
    {
        // Copy the material
        g_pMeshMaterials[i] = d3dxMaterials[i].MatD3D;

        // Set the ambient color for the material (D3DX does not do this)
        g_pMeshMaterials[i].Ambient = g_pMeshMaterials[i].Diffuse;

        g_pMeshTextures[i] = NULL;
        if( d3dxMaterials[i].pTextureFilename != NULL &&
            lstrlenA( d3dxMaterials[i].pTextureFilename ) > 0 )
        {
            // Create the texture
            if( FAILED( D3DXCreateTextureFromFileA( g_pd3dDevice,
                                                    d3dxMaterials[i].pTextureFilename,
                                                    &g_pMeshTextures[i] ) ) )
            {
                // If texture is not in current folder, try parent folder
                const CHAR* strPrefix = "..\\";
                CHAR strTexture[MAX_PATH];
                strcpy_s( strTexture, MAX_PATH, strPrefix );
                strcat_s( strTexture, MAX_PATH, d3dxMaterials[i].pTextureFilename );
                // If texture is not in current folder, try parent folder
                if( FAILED( D3DXCreateTextureFromFileA( g_pd3dDevice,
                                                        strTexture,
                                                        &g_pMeshTextures[i] ) ) )
                {
                    MessageBox( NULL, L"Could not find texture map", L"Meshes.exe", MB_OK );
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Done with the material buffer
    pD3DXMtrlBuffer->Release();

    return S_OK;
}




//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Name: Cleanup()
// Desc: Releases all previously initialized objects
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
VOID Cleanup()
{
    if( g_pMeshMaterials != NULL )
        delete[] g_pMeshMaterials;

    if( g_pMeshTextures )
    {
        for( DWORD i = 0; i < g_dwNumMaterials; i++ )
        {
            if( g_pMeshTextures[i] )
                g_pMeshTextures[i]->Release();
        }
        delete[] g_pMeshTextures;
    }
    if( g_pMesh != NULL )
        g_pMesh->Release();

    if( g_pd3dDevice != NULL )
        g_pd3dDevice->Release();

    if( g_pD3D != NULL )
        g_pD3D->Release();
}



//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Name: SetupMatrices()
// Desc: Sets up the world, view, and projection transform matrices.
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
VOID SetupMatrices()
{
    // Set up world matrix
    D3DXMATRIXA16 matWorld;
    D3DXMatrixRotationY( &matWorld, NULL );
    g_pd3dDevice->SetTransform( D3DTS_WORLD, &matWorld );

    // Set up our view matrix. A view matrix can be defined given an eye point,
    // a point to lookat, and a direction for which way is up. Here, we set the
    // eye five units back along the z-axis and up three units, look at the 
    // origin, and define "up" to be in the y-direction.
    D3DXVECTOR3 vEyePt( 10.0f, 200.0f,-500.0f );
    D3DXVECTOR3 vLookatPt( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );
    D3DXVECTOR3 vUpVec( 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f );
    D3DXMATRIXA16 matView;
    D3DXMatrixLookAtLH( &matView, &vEyePt, &vLookatPt, &vUpVec );
    g_pd3dDevice->SetTransform( D3DTS_VIEW, &matView );

    // For the projection matrix, we set up a perspective transform (which
    // transforms geometry from 3D view space to 2D viewport space, with
    // a perspective divide making objects smaller in the distance). To build
    // a perpsective transform, we need the field of view (1/4 pi is common),
    // the aspect ratio, and the near and far clipping planes (which define at
    // what distances geometry should be no longer be rendered).
    D3DXMATRIXA16 matProj;
    D3DXMatrixPerspectiveFovLH( &matProj, D3DX_PI / 4, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1000.0f );
    g_pd3dDevice->SetTransform( D3DTS_PROJECTION, &matProj );
}




//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Name: Render()
// Desc: Draws the scene
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
VOID Render()
{
    // Clear the backbuffer and the zbuffer
    g_pd3dDevice->Clear( 0, NULL, D3DCLEAR_TARGET | D3DCLEAR_ZBUFFER,
                         D3DCOLOR_XRGB( 0, 0, 255 ), 1.0f, 0 );

    // Begin the scene
    if( SUCCEEDED( g_pd3dDevice->BeginScene() ) )
    {
        // Setup the world, view, and projection matrices
        SetupMatrices();

        // Meshes are divided into subsets, one for each material. Render them in
        // a loop
        for( DWORD i = 0; i < g_dwNumMaterials; i++ )
        {
            // Set the material and texture for this subset
            g_pd3dDevice->SetMaterial( &g_pMeshMaterials[i] );
            g_pd3dDevice->SetTexture( 0, g_pMeshTextures[i] );

            // Draw the mesh subset
            g_pMesh->DrawSubset( i );
        }

        // End the scene
        g_pd3dDevice->EndScene();
    }

    // Present the backbuffer contents to the display
    g_pd3dDevice->Present( NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL );
}




//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Name: MsgProc()
// Desc: The window's message handler
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
LRESULT WINAPI MsgProc( HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
{
    switch( msg )
    {
        case WM_DESTROY:
            Cleanup();
            PostQuitMessage( 0 );
            return 0;
    }

    return DefWindowProc( hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam );
}




//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Name: WinMain()
// Desc: The application's entry point
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
INT WINAPI wWinMain( HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE, LPWSTR, INT )
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER( hInst );

    // Register the window class
    WNDCLASSEX wc =
    {
        sizeof( WNDCLASSEX ), CS_CLASSDC, MsgProc, 0L, 0L,
        GetModuleHandle( NULL ), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,
        L"D3D Tutorial", NULL
    };
    RegisterClassEx( &wc );

    // Create the application's window
    HWND hWnd = CreateWindow( L"D3D Tutorial", L"D3D Tutorial 06: Meshes",
                              WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 100, 100, 300, 300,
                              NULL, NULL, wc.hInstance, NULL );

    // Initialize Direct3D
    if( SUCCEEDED( InitD3D( hWnd ) ) )
    {
        // Create the scene geometry
        if( SUCCEEDED( InitGeometry() ) )
        {
            // Show the window
            ShowWindow( hWnd, SW_SHOWDEFAULT );
            UpdateWindow( hWnd );

            // Enter the message loop
            MSG msg;
            ZeroMemory( &msg, sizeof( msg ) );
            while( msg.message != WM_QUIT )
            {
                if( PeekMessage( &msg, NULL, 0U, 0U, PM_REMOVE ) )
                {
                    TranslateMessage( &msg );
                    DispatchMessage( &msg );
                }
                else
                    Render();
            }
        }
    }

    UnregisterClass( L"D3D Tutorial", wc.hInstance );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A mesh cannot be "pixelated", it is vector information. Perhaps you mean the textures on it? In any case, please post a screenshot of the "good" and the "bad" rendering of the mesh. Simply posting all the code involved is also not a good idea.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i figured out... Yes you are right the texture were very low at resolution cause i haven't setted the proper values for backbufferheight and backbufferwidth at presentparams. But now i face a hole different problem. I am on windows 7 and for performance issus i have to use LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9EX and for some reason when i load the x file i get E_INVALIDARG - An invalid parameter was passed to the returning function. Any Ideas why??? when i try the same code with the classic LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 then everything is working fine...

Comment: Turn on debug output for the device and see, what the problem is.